Angular firebase sign in anonymously not working
I have an Angular 17.3.6 with the package @angular/fire version 17.0.1 installed. When i try to sign in anonymously with Firebase, I get the following error:

SignIn Error: FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/admin-restricted-operation).

I have already checked in Firebase console if anonymous sign in is permitted, and indeed it is active and should be working.
My auth service is the following:
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { onAuthStateChanged, Auth, User, signInAnonymously } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthService {
  public user: User;
  constructor(private auth: Auth, private router: Router) {
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      if (user) {
        this.user = user;
      } else {
        this.signIn();
      }
    });
  }

  public getToken() {
    try {
      return this.user.getIdToken();
    } catch(error) {
      this.router.navigateByUrl('');
      return Promise.resolve('');
    }
  }

  public async signIn() {
    try {
      const data = await signInAnonymously(this.auth);
      this.user = data.user;
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(`SignIn Error: ${err}`);
    }
  }
}

If I try signInWithEmailAndPassword or signInWithCustomToken, it works just fine.
Below is a print from the error in console window.

And the Firebase console with the anonymous login active:

